# How can i find the port number of my android device connected by USB?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to telnet into my android device but to do that i would need the port number of my device, which i dont know how to find. in case of emulator the port number is written in the title but my CPU doesnt support emulator.
Please tell me how can i find the port number of my android device?

Comment: did you read this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5609094/2035645

Comment: @shantanu thanks bro got it now. please rate up this question up i need to level up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, you should use "ADB shell" if you want to connect to your phone, it does not need a port number

Comment: thanks man for help. please rate this question up i need to level up